# How to run windows command in client side(accessing client machine using browser)?

Tags: plugins, activex, webbrowser-control, japplet, google-nativeclient

I found many questions about same issue in Stackoverflow. But could not find any satisfactory answers.
My problem is: 
I have to run "iperf client" in client machine(assuming windows) using command line in client windows machine and get the statistics.
Currently my server is written in PHP(I am ready to shift to any platform) given that I shall be able to run iperf command on client machine.

I searched and found that, Java applet, ActiveX control or Plugins(like Google Talk plugin). Can someone suggest me the best and easiest approach here(with some reference links if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run an arbitrary command on the client side using Native Client. What you can do is invoke [Pepper API functions](https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepperc/) from your extension. Another thing you can do is access the Chrome extension API from Javascript. If none of these have the information you need, feel free to suggest new features on the [native-client-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/native-client-discuss) mailing list. Note that invoking "any Windows command" cannot be reasonably made part of a client-side application, due to security issues.